# Putting horizontally scrolling UICollectionView into vertically scrolling UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a vertically scrolling UICollectionview with different elements. In one section, I would like to show multiple horizontally scrollable elements. This is how my setup looks like:

A Prototype Cell (subclass of UICollectionViewCell):

```
class SlidingCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 8
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(130, 100)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    return collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("SwipeContainedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Whatever I do, it just doesn't scroll horizontally :-(. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that you don't have the nested CollectionView inside an UIView